# Allow user to enter a simple formula to calculate the value

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I create a column which allows the user to enter a formula to derive the amount?  ie:  =(5*160)*.85    I would like the formula to be retained when it is edited, but the value shown in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could add JavaScript to the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx pages and use the JavaScript "eval" function to do the calculation and write the result to another column.

```
eval( textFromTextBoxWithFormula )
```

But as you are working with SharePoint Online, this would only work with the Classic UI, and would not work with a QuickEdit view. If you were working with an on-prem SharePoint, you could edit the forms, or create a custom Event Receiver to do the update.

If the formula follows a fixed pattern like (a * b) * c, then you create three columns for the three values and add a Calculated column to do the math.

```
=([Column A] * [Column B]) * [Column C]
```

Note: the parens are not needed as multiplication is associative.

Answer (score 0):

You can create four Number columns and named them as Number1, Number2,Number3,Total.

Then custom the list using InfoPath via "Customize Form", and set default value for the Total column as:

```
Number1 * Number2 * Number3
```

The result is like:
[image]

After that, publish the form to Sharepoint.